# Abrir JFrame no Java maximizado

Tags: java, swing

Estou com um problema, estou criando um JFrame e quero que ele abra maximizado. Estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

O tamanho do JFrame está maximizado, mas o botão para eu maximizar ainda está disponível, então, se eu clicar nele, ele aumenta a tela um pouquinho mais ainda.

Quero abrir ele maximizado de verdade, com o botão de restaurar tamanho disponível. Alguém sabe o que tem de errado no código? Ou como fazer? Obrigado.

Comment: O objeto frame é de uma classe JFrame?

Comment: Fiz o teste e funcionou normalmente. Você está fazendo isso antes ou depois de setar setVisible?

Comment: É um JFrame sim. E estou fazendo depois do setVisible. Não encontrei explicação plausivel pra não funcionar, pois em outra classe eu uso o mesmo código e maximiza certinho.

Comment: Tente não setar diretamente o setExtendedState logo após o setvisible.

Comment: É assim que to fazendo. Logo após.

Comment: Opa, tentei logo após o setLocation e deu certo!

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está centralizando o frame antes de centralizá-lo. Centralize-o primeiro e depois maximize:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

> [`setLocationRelativeTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo(java.awt.Component))
>
> ...
>
> - If the component is null, or the GraphicsConfiguration associated with this component is null, the window is placed in the center of the screen. The center point can be obtained with the GraphicsEnvironment.getCenterPoint method.
>
> ...

Em tradução livre:

> ...
>
> - Se o componente é null, ou a GraphicsConfiguration associada a este componente é null, a janela é colocada no centro da tela. O centro do ponto pode ser obtido pelo método GraphicsEnvironment.getCenterPoint.
>
> ...